# ServiceStack.Text.EnumMemberSerializer not working with Swagger plugin

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-text, servicestack-bsd

I'm using ServiceStack v 3.9.71 and the `ServiceStack.Text.EnumMemberSerializer` assembly to serialize enums into readable text.

This works great, my enum values are serialized into the name I've specified using the `EnumMemberAttribute`.

The problem, though, is Swagger does not use my names. My guess is it just calls the `.ToString()` method on the enum values rather than the `EnumMemberAttribute` value.

Here is the order in which I setup the serialization. (In AppHost):

```
new EnumSerializerConfigurator()
            .WithEnumTypes(new Type[] { typeof(MyEnum) })
            .Configure();

Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
```

It doesn't seem to matter if the enum serializer is set before or after the swagger feature is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with, in my opinion, a better solution. I wrote a class that extends the `ApiAllowableValuesAttribute`:

```
public class ApiAllowableValues2Attribute : ApiAllowableValuesAttribute
{
    public ApiAllowableValues2Attribute(string name, Type enumType)
        : base(name)
    {
        List<string> values = new List<string>();

        var enumTypeValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType);

        // loop through each enum value
        foreach (var etValue in enumTypeValues)
        {
            // get the member in order to get the enumMemberAttribute
            var member = enumType.GetMember(
                Enum.GetName(enumType, etValue)).First();

            // get the enumMember attribute
            var enumMemberAttr = member.GetCustomAttributes(
                typeof(System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute), true).First();

            // get the enumMember attribute value
            var enumMemberValue = ((System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute)enumMemberAttr).Value;

            values.Add(enumMemberValue);

        }

        Values = values.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The client object:

```
public class MyClientObject
{
    [Description("The name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [Description("The client object type")]
    [ApiAllowableValues2("MyEnum", typeof(MyEnum))]
    public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

Now you don't have to specify the names again or worry about a name change breaking your Swagger documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the Swagger code does not use ServiceStack.Text.EnumMemberSerializer when  parsing enum values. It only uses an `Enum.GetValues` [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/SwaggerApiService.cs#L304). Note that this is still the same in v4.

You can submit a pull request to make this change, but I'm not familiar with EnumMemberSerialzer and how it allows for retrieving the list of enum options. You may instead be able to use a string property decorated with [ApiAllowableValues](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/ApiAllowableValuesAttribute.cs) to achieve the affect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with (with the help of bpruitt-goddard, thanks mate):

The enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Value One")]
    Value1 = 1,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Value Two")]
    Value2 = 2,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Value Three")]
    Value3 = 3
}
```

The client object:

```
public class MyClientObject
{
    [Description("The name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [Description("The client object type")]
    [ApiAllowableValues("MyEnum", "Value One", "Value Two", "Value Three")]
    public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

Inside the AppHost:

```
new EnumSerializerConfigurator()
            .WithEnumTypes(new Type[] { typeof(MyEnum) })
            .Configure();
```

Now the enum is serialized properly and the Swagger documentation is correct. The only issue with this is having the names in two different places. Perhaps there is a way to check the names match via a unit test.